# how to solve this error: object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Tags: r

[This is part of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5azsG.png) I want to find range, mean and sd for all variables in my dataset. I used the for loop in the picture but shows the error like object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
> mean <- c() range <- c() sd <- c()
> 
> dyad.all_subset <- subset(dyad.all, select=c(BAA,BAF,`Data
> Science`,`Life Science`,Engineer,`Previous Raised`,`Max
> Raise`,Age,`Patent Numbers`,Patent,`Committed Amount ($K)`))
> dyad.all_subset$BAA <- as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$BAA)
> dyad.all_subset$BAF <- as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$BAF)
> dyad.all_subset$`Data Science` <- as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$`Data
> Science`) dyad.all_subset$`Life Science` <-
> as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$`Life Science`) dyad.all_subset$Engineer <-
> as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$Engineer) dyad.all_subset$`Previous Raised`
> <- as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$`Previous Raised`) dyad.all_subset$`Max
> Raise` <- as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$`Max Raise`) dyad.all_subset$Age
> <- as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$Age) dyad.all_subset$`Patent Numbers` <-
> as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$`Patent Numbers`) dyad.all_subset$Patent <-
> as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$Patent) dyad.all_subset$`Committed Amount
> ($K)` <- as.numeric(dyad.all_subset$`Committed Amount ($K)`)
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> for(i in 1:nrow(dyad.all_subset)){   range[i] <-
> range(dyad.all_subset[[i]],na.rm=T)   mean[i] <-
> mean(dyad.all_subset[[i]], na.rm=T)   sd[i] <-
> sd(dyad.all_subset[[i]],na.rm=T) }
```

[image: This is my code and error]

Comment: You need to initialize `range`, `mean` and `sd` before the loop. R thinks you want to subset the functions with these names.

Comment: I have initialized those as vectors, such as range <- c(), but still has the problem.

Comment: A good practice up front is to never name your variables after base R functions. If you don't do any subsetting (using `\`[<-\`` as here), then you can get away with it but it's still a bad practice. In this case, the use of `\`[<\`` is highlighting the fact that it is finding the *functions* first (which seems odd to me). Change your variable names to non-functions and your problem should go away.

Comment: Tangent: you are iterating over the *rows* of a frame, and for each *row* in the frame, you are calculating the range, mean, and sd stats for the `i`th *column*. Your code is almost certainly going to break at some point unless you have a perfect square. (There are certainly better ways to do this, btw. I'm not going to suggest code based off no data and a pic of code, perhaps you can edit your question and make it reproducible.)

Comment: Just updated !!

Comment: The first line of your code is a syntax error. It doesn't initialize anything. There are more syntax errors. Mind your linebreaks.

Comment: Another error: your `range` *variable* (bad name) is assigning the return value of the `range(.)` *function* (which is length 2) into a spot for a single value. So even if we could reproduce this (we cannot), that is a syntax error. Amy, please [edit] your question and (1) as Roland put it, mind your newlines, this code is currently syntactically invalid, and (2) provide the output from `dput(head(dyad.all_subset))`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop using variables named `range`, `mean`, and `sd`. It may look obvious, but when troubleshooting code, it can be difficult to read (and therefore maintain).
2. I simplified a lot of what you did here into simpler expressions. You should now have a vector named `mu` with the averages of each column; `sigma` with standard-deviations of each; and a *matrix* named `rng` that has two rows, the min and max for each column.

```r
cols <- c("BAA", "BAF", "Data Science", "Life Science", "Engineer", "Previous Raised",
          "Max Raise", "Age", "Patent Numbers", "Patent", "Committed Amount ($K)")
dyad.all_subset <- subset(dyad.all, select = cols)
dyad.all_subset[] <- lapply(dyad.all_subset, as.numeric)

rng   <- sapply(dyad.all_subset, range, na.rm = TRUE)
mu    <- sapply(dyad.all_subset, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
sigma <- sapply(dyad.all_subset, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The `[]` on the LHS of the `lapply` reassignment is intentional, without it the variable will be a named `list`, not a `data.frame`.

`lapply` and `sapply` evaluate a function (e.g., `range`, `mean`, ...) on each element of its first argument. Since a `data.frame` is, for the most part, a `list` where all elements are the same length (generally speaking), then each column is processed at a time. For instance,

```r
sapply(dyad.all_subset, range, na.rm = TRUE)

## is effectively the same as
c(range(dyad.all_subset[[1]], na.rm = TRUE),
  range(dyad.all_subset[[2]], na.rm = TRUE),
  range(dyad.all_subset[[3]], na.rm = TRUE),
  ...,
  range(dyad.all_subset[[n]], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the variables `range`, `mean` and `sd`. They are short, yet easy to understand, which is after all reason why they are used to name functions `range()`, `mean()` and `sd()`. They are less suitable when found without context or when one is working with several different means, ranges and standard deviations, but then the problem is in a lack of contextualization or encapsulation rather than in names itself. On top of it, changing `range`, `mean` and `sd` into `rng`, `mu` and `sigma` is only painting the problem with a different colour.

Comment: Instead, consider wrapping all this into `summary.dyad` function and returning `list("mean"=mean,"sd"=sd, "range"=range)`.

In addition, `subset` is a nice shortcut, but for interactive use only.

Comment: Your suggestion for wrapping in a named list is great.  But your statement that using `mu` is *"painting the problem with a different colour"* is both incomplete and missing the point. The problem is *ambiguity* in some expressions (that are not in the OP's code); switching to `mu` to me is clear (stats classes often use the greek letter for it) and, more importantly, is never ambiguous. While variable-naming in general is subjective and not something I'm arguing about, symbol-ambiguity can (and will) cause problems.

Comment: The risk of using `subset` outside of interactive use is mostly based on its ability to use non-standard evaluation, that is not being used here. (One *advantage* of using `subset` like this is that it works the same across `data.frame`, `tbl_df`, and `data.table`. I admit that it's not necessarily common for users to use all three interchangeably, but if code is intended to be agnostic, it is often useful to find unified access.)

Comment: `mu`, `sigma` and `rng` is not magically more meaningful than `range`, `mean` or `sd`. The reason why math/stats uses greek symbols is that writing "mean" or "standard deviation" is just too long and it's better to abstract a bit to make algebraic manipulation easier. When programming, its often better to use names that are more obviously meaningful. I really do not see what kind of *ambiguity* you are talking about, especially since you have not mentioned or demonstrated any. Most of the problem with potentially ambiguous names can be solved by making functions.

Comment: I am partial to the `subset` for object-agnostic subsetting. But I have been burned by a non-standard evaluation more often than I had to build a truly object-agnostic code.

Comment: I've been burned, too, which is why I rarely use its NSE.

Answer (score 0):

@r2evans answer is correct. However, for better practices, consider:

#### 1. Wrapping into a function:

Your code forms a logical unit. Even if you do not reuse it, you have isolated it, named it and set some expectation.

```
dyad_summary = function(data, columns=NULL){
    if(!is.null(columns))
        data = subset(data, select=columns)

    data[] = lapply(data, as.numeric)

    range = sapply(data, range, na.rm=TRUE)
    mean = sapply(data, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
    sd = sapply(data, sd, na.rm=TRUE)

    list("range" = range, "mean" = mean, "sd" = sd)
    }
```

#### 2. Use standard subsetting instead of  `subset`

`subset` is a nice shorthand but should be used only interactively.

```
# instead of:
data = subset(data, select=columns)

# write:
data = data[,columns]

# it is even shorter!
```

#### 3. Play with S3 classes:

S3 classes are not a true object-oriented system, but essentially lightweight dispatch system and naming convenience:

```
class(dyad) = "dyad"
# Or even better:
class(dyad) = c("dyad", class(dyad))

# Define function with summary generics:
summary.dyad = function(...){
    ...
    }

summary(dyad)
```

Don't worry that you do not understand what "generics", "class" or "object-oriented" means, this is essentially everything you need to know for simple S3 usage.

And since you are there, the class of the `summary` function can be `dyad.summary` and you can make your own `print` function by writing: `print.dyad.summary`.

#### 4. Document your functions:

This will make them even more readable so next week, when you forget --why-- did you wrote your function, you can just read your documentation.

```
#' Summarize Dyad data
#'
#' Converts all or just selected columns to a numeric type,
#' and then returns their mean, standard deviation and range.
#' `NAs` in data or introduced during the conversion are omitted.
#'
#' @param data dyad data
#' @param **optional** vector specifying subset of columns that will be summarized
#' @return a list of mean, standard deviation and range for each column
#' in the dyad data.
summary.dyad = function(data, columns=NULL){
   ...
   }
```

When documented in this format, you are making already making `roxygen2` documentation if you want to throw the function into a package later in the project lifespawn.

Comment: This all may be decent advice but is way above OPs level of competence. They are not even able to notice when R throws an error! Also, S3 classes to quickly calculate range, mean and SD?